# Iptables rules to only whitelist SIP providers

Tags: firewall, iptables, asterisk

I have an Asterisk box sitting behind an ADSL router/modem.  There are no other services on the Asterisk box, just telephony.  I am getting a lot of traffic which I think are SIP probes.  I've installed the [sippot rbl client](http://www.opentek.ca/sippot) which adds 1400 addresses to block to my iptables, but I'm still getting unsolicited traffic.

I think the solution is  to block all traffic on Asterisk except local traffic ( 192.168.1.n), and VPN traffic ( Hamachi  25.213.n.n ), and only whitelist the 2 VOIP providers I use.  I don't have any outside the office SIP lines, so don't need fancy rules to track mobile users, or other offices.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add something like this to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "local traffic"
-A INPUT -s 25.213.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "VPN traffic"
-A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4/32 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "SIP provider 1"
-A INPUT -s 5.6.7.8/32 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "SIP provider 2"
```

These rules should go just above the default deny rule, which typically looks something like this:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited -m comment --comment "default deny"
```

You can also add things using the `iptables` command, but without knowing what rule number you want to insert, it's easier to just edit the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fail2ban to ban bad attacks

IF you use vpn, you can just turn off port 5060 forwarding on your router.